# Bitfields vs. Polymorphism for game map object attributes

Tags: c++, optimization, polymorphism, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

This optimzation question has been bugging me for the last day.

In my program (a simple roguelike game), I use bitwise flags to store the attributes of map objects, such as if they are solid, or if they are rendered.  However, I could accomplish the thing using polymorphism to return the appropriate value.

My question is, is either way significantly faster or slower than the other way when used in a linked list loop?  Also, is one better practice than the other?

An example of the code:

```
XMapObject *List = ListStart;

while(List != NULL)
{
    if(List->MapObjectFlags & MAPOBJECTFLAG_RENDER)
      OR
    if(List->Render())
    {
        return List->Type;
    }
    else
    {
        List = List->Next;
    }
}

bool XMapObject::Render()
{
     return 1;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think, it's a premature optimization you are doing.

Comment: Also you could create non-vrtual inline Render() member function that would simply `return MapObjectFlags & MAPOBJECTFLAG_RENDER` and use it instead of implicit bitwise operation. Then if you decide to switch to another checking method, you'll just change the implementation.

Comment: @n0rd: It most definitely is premature, but the question has been bugging me as I was policing some older sources in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bitwise operation is always faster than a virtual function call.

Comment: I thought so. After thinking about it too, its also more flexible.

Comment: How it can be more flexible, if number of bits in a single `int` (or whatever you use for storing) is quite limited?

Comment: More flexible than my original example, which has the hard coded return.